# Python classes and Method

Tags: python

```
class Shape:

    def __init__(self, x, y, name, age):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        description = "This shape has not been described yet"
        author = "Nobody has claimed to make this shape yet"

    def area(self):
        return self.x * self.y

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.x + 2 * self.y

    def describe(self,text):
        self.description = text

    def authorName(self,text):
        self.author = text

    def scaleSize(self,scale):
        self.x = self.x * scale
        self.y = self.y * scale
```

How do i print the attributes in authorName , describe and  scaleSize as so far i have only been able achieve this result.

```
objectname = Shape(8,10, 'Peter Adom', '55')

print(objectname.name)
print(objectname.area())
print(objectname.perimeter())
```

Comment: `describe` is not a "getter" it is a "setter". It acts to set the author name for some `Shape` object. You would need some function `def printAuthor(self): print(self.author)` then you could call `objectname.printAuthor()`

Comment: you can print it directly ? `print objectname.author` .

Answer (score 1):

You can see that the functions `area` and `perimeter` have a `return` clause, that's because they are supposed to compute something that would not be directly accessible (you have `x` and `y` but you don't have an attribute that stores the area or the perimeter.
This is common in programming because if you had an `area` attribute, this could differ from the value computed by `self.x * self.y`, bringing inconsistencies.

The methods `describe`, `authorName` and `scaleSize` instead are used to change some of the attributes of the object. They do not return anything, they *set* values in the object.

In order to retrieve the attributes of the object you should just access them directly. But this doesn't work for `description` and `author` because you are not setting the attributes in the object namespace. In fact the lines in method `__init__` should be:

```
self.description = "This shape has not been described yet"
self.author = "Nobody has claimed to make this shape yet"
```

After that you will be able to do:

```
objectname = Shape(8,10, 'Peter Adom', '55')

print(objectname.author)             # Nobody has claimed to make this shape yet
objectname.authorName("Me")
print(objectname.author)             # Me

print(objectname.description)             # This shape has not been described yet
objectname.describe("Wonderful shape")
print(objectname.description)                  # Wonderful shape
```

You should consider naming your setter in a way that makes unequivocal their purpose, for example `setAuthor` and `setDescription`.